# How to convert an SVG file into a JPEG?

Tags: svg, jpeg, sf-symbols

I'm using SF Symbols in buttons for a Mac App, but since I'm trying to customize their colors to better fit the theme. I'm thinking of converting the vector based file into a JPEG image.

Comment: I can't help with the conversion app recommendation. But please do not use JPEG. JPEGs are for photographic images. Use something like a PNG instead.

Comment: By converting you will lose the quality. You can use open-source [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.1/) to edit SVG easily and change the colors to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

`rsvg` can convert SVG to PNG.
PNG is lossless, while JPEG distorts image pixels, which also affects colors.

[`brew install librsvg`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/librsvg)
[`rsvg-convert in.svg out.png`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsvg)